# Javascript while loop = new to javascript

Tags: javascript, while-loop

Could anybody tell me why my code isn't working here, thanks in advance, scratchpad is telling me I'm missing a ';' but I can't see where...:

```
var x= " ";
var i >= 101;

while (i<=200, i%10);
{
  x = x + i + "\n ";
  i++;
}
alert(x);
```

Comment: you initialization of `i` is wrong. you have a condition.

Comment: use a tool like jshint.com

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while

Comment: what do ypu want with `i%10`;

Comment: I'd like to start a new line after each set of 10 integers....

Answer (score 0):

You need a proper initialization. What you had, is a condition, which can not used for a declaration of a variable, without an assignment to the variable.

```
var i = 101;
//    ^
```

The other point, is the misleading comma operator for the condition of the while loop and a semicolon after the while condition, which ends the block for the while loop without working with the next code block.

```
while (i<=200)
//           ^^^^ without another expression and without semicolon
```

```js
var x = '',
    i = 101;

while (i <= 200) {
    x += i + '\n';
    if (!(i % 10)) {
        x += '\n';
    }
    i++;
}
alert(x);
```

Comment: Thanks so much Nina

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Chrome DevTools. Use the keyboard shortcuts Ctrl+Shift+I (Windows) or Cmd+Opt+I (Mac)

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >=(…)
```

Here is your fault.